# Text Contains two different strings? WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, contains, assert

I am trying to assert whether two or more strings are evident. My code currently only looks for "Good". Is there a way to look for "Good" or "Bad"?

```
    public class Test
{
    public static bool FindText()
    {
        var conf = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("foo"));

        if (conf.Text.Contains("Good"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        throw new Exception("Text not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seriously asking how an **or** condition works in C# or am I missing something?

Comment: please do a bit of research before asking questions

Answer (score 1):

I would use `System.Linq` and check against all elements of an array, if there could possibly be more than two valid strings.

```
public class Test
{
  public static bool FindText()
  {
    var stringsToFind = new [] { "Good", "Bad" };

    var conf = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("foo"));

    if (stringsToFind.Any(s => conf.Text.Contains(s))
    {
        return true;
    }

    throw new Exception("Text not found");
  }
}
```

for only two elements to check I would propably just extend the if condition with a second condition and an `or`.

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to find a string, always make the string variable to upper or lower case. Since it's case sensitive, when the text is "GoOd", you won't find a match looking for "Good"

```
if(conf.Text.ToUpper().Contains("GOOD")){
//do something
}
else if(conf.Text.ToUpper().Contains("BAD")){
//do something else
}
```

You could also put then in only one "if" statement, if you're only interested in finding out if there's any of those by using

```
if(conf.Text.ToUpper().Contains("GOOD") || conf.Text.ToUpper().Contains("BAD")){
//do something for both cases
}
```

Answer (score 0):

|| is the operator for the OR operation

```
 if (conf.Text.Contains("Good") || conf.Text.Contains("Bad"))
```

PD : Stop whatever you are doing and take a look to the language docs, you need to understand what are you doing.

Comment: Thanks. This was admittedly a noob question but I'm new to this.

Comment: Everybody is new at some point !, but you are jumping to a place that you need to know that beforehand, so you can run easy :)